# "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/mac/Library/Preferences/truffle-nodejs/config.json.tmp-54458241332dcbd4'"

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, truffle, erc20

I am trying to migrate a contract with truffle command "truffle develop" and here is the output

```
mac@FAVOURs-MBP truffleLearning % truffle develop              
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/mac/Library/Preferences/truffle-nodejs/config.json.tmp-54458241332dcbd4'
    at openSync (node:fs:601:3)
    at attempt (/Users/mac/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/atomically/dist/utils/retryify.js:33:1)
    at Object.writeFileSync (/Users/mac/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/atomically/dist/index.js:136:1)
    at Conf._write (/Users/mac/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/node_modules/conf/dist/source/index.js:375:1)
    at Conf.set store [as store] (/Users/mac/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/node_modules/conf/dist/source/index.js:296:1)
    at Conf.set (/Users/mac/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/node_modules/conf/dist/source/index.js:189:1)
    at Object.getOrGenerateMnemonic (/Users/mac/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/mnemonics/mnemonic.js:33:1)
    at Object.getAccountsInfo (/Users/mac/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/mnemonics/mnemonic.js:47:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/Users/mac/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/develop/run.js:31:1)
    at runCommand (/Users/mac/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command-utils.js:297:1)
Truffle v5.9.2 (core: 5.9.2)
Node v18.16.0
mac@FAVOURs-MBP truffleLearning %
```

I was expecting truffle to deploy and migrate the compiled Smart Contracts